# CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. while using iframe in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, mern

I'm looking to access a [site](https://gkwhelps.herokuapp.com) from a button using `iframe`. This site authorizes access to all domain names.
Here is the code for my button:

```
<Button
        component={NavLink}
        activeClassName={classes.activeBtn}
        to="/searchEngine"
        className={classes.buttonItemMiddle}
      >
        {location.pathname == '/searchEngine' ? (
          <Home fontSize="large" style={{ color: 'rgb(0,133,243)' }} />
        ) : (
          <HomeOutlined fontSize="large" />
        )}
      </Button>
```

Here is my code in `App.js`:

```
<Route path='/searchEngine' component={() => { 
                          <iframe src="https://gkwhelps.herokuapp.com" title="Search engine"></iframe>
                          return null;
                          }}/>
```

But when I run my app and click the button, it returns nothing and I get the following error when inspecting my code on the browser:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O7fVlw-' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I reloaded the solution from the Internet and specifically from this question on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/questions/71799169/socket-io-socket-server-doesnt-console-anything-has-been-blocked-by-cors-pol?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=fr&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=sc) and from this [blog](https://www.journaldunet.fr/web-tech/developpement/1497441-comment-resoudre-l-erreur-cors-dans-axios-et-y-ajouter-access-control-allow-origin/) and added the following code in my `App.js` file:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://gkwhelps.herokuapp.com"),
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"),
  next(),
})
```

but that did not solve the problem. here is the content of my backend `index.js` file:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require("dotenv").config()
const app = express()
const http = require('http')
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)

const UserRoutes = require('./routes/User')
const AuthRoutes = require('./routes/Auth')
const PostRoutes = require('./routes/Post')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const {MONGODB_URI} = require("./config")

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  
  io.req = req
  req.io = io
  next()
})

app.use('/api/auth', AuthRoutes)
app.use('/api/user', UserRoutes)
app.use('/api/post', PostRoutes)

require('./socket')(io)

mongoose
  .connect(MONGODB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('database connected')
    server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server started on port ${PORT}`))
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

To solve this problem,I also search the solution in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin) and in this [blog](https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-react-express/) I modified my `index.js` file as follows:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'localhost:3000')
  io.req = req
  req.io = io
  next()
})
```

but without success.
My frontend `package.json` file is here:

```
{
  "name": "firebase",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.61",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.1",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.11.8",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "0.27.2",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "emoji-picker-react": "^3.5.1",
    
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jwt-decode": "3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.4",
    "npm": "^8.11.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-eva-icons": "0.0.8",
    "react-hook-google-maps": "^0.0.3",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "4.5.1",
    "words-to-numbers": "1.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  }
}
```

my backend `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm start\" \"npm run client\"",
    "start": "node backend/index.js",
    "server": "nodemon backend/index.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix frontend"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.7.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.7",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.2.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because your frontend is trying to send requests to an endpoint running on the same domain(localhost). But this your error is not thrown by express. That's why the solution you try to apply didn't work.

**Since Socket.IO v3, you need to explicitly enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) event when you are working on localhost.**

intead `const io = require('socket.io')(server)` in your code you can do that :

```
const { Server }= require('socket.io');
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000"
  }
});
```

You can read the official doc [handling cors](https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/) `